# How do I uninstall pcloud client properly?

Tags: uninstall, cloud

I downloaded and ran a binary from their website (not a debian package) with [these instructions](https://www.pcloud.com/how-to-install-pcloud-drive-linux.html). I can't seem to find an uninstall.

Comment: It might help if you link the site with the tutorial/instructions you followed to install it. Not everyone knows every software. And it might give people a clue on how to approach writing an answer for you.

Comment: And remember that pCloud does not perform a real installation. It's more an "on the fly" software. Indeed, if you quit the program, your pCloud folder will get empty. I suppose you can only remove all the files as suggested by the other users.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not official, but you can find most of the files with:

```
locate pcloud
```

(If no files are listed, run updatedb.)

Delete the following:

```
~/.pcloud/
~/.config/pcloud/
~/.config/autostart/pcloud.desktop
~/.local/share/applications/appimagekit-pcloud.desktop
~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/appimagekit-pcloud.png
```

This is unofficial, so some settings might still remain.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and so I decided to contact pCloud directly. I was promptly  informed to delete the following files:

1. /home/current-user/.config/pcloud
2. /home/current-user/.pcloud
3. /home/current-user/.config/autostart/pcloud.desktop
4. all instances of "pcloud" you have downloaded /home/downloads/pcloud

Comment: It's a bit disappointing pcloud still has no publicly documented and easy method of uninstalling their app.